# Gatsby no longer developing due to 'originalFactory.call' is undefined

Tags: gatsby, server-side-rendering

I can no longer develop my Gatsby site due to:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'originalFactory.call')

[image]

I can build the site, but I cannot load any of the pages while using `gatsby develop`. I know this has something to do with SSR. Is there a way around this?

---

**EDIT**
Just realized that when [Gatsby-browser.js](https://github.com/tnorlund/Blog/blob/master/gatsby-browser.js) is removed, it works properly. It won't render properly, but there's no runtime error. Is there anything else I can share to help find an answer?

Comment: Can you add more details? When happen? What have you tried? Do you have any specific or special configuration on your SSR?

Comment: This started happening when I upgraded to Gatsby v3+. The [SSR](https://github.com/tnorlund/Blog/blob/master/gatsby-ssr.js) is fairly standard. I don't know whether this is a Gatsby problem or an issue with the code I've written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following snippet instead of your `onServiceWorkerUpdateReady`'s  function?

```
export const onServiceWorkerUpdateReady = () => {
  const answer = window.confirm(
    `This application has been updated. ` +
      `Reload to display the latest version?`
  )
  if (answer === true) {
    window.location.reload()
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share a reference & explanation, @ferran-buireu? I ask because I'm getting the same issue after migrating v2 to v3 to v4, but no keywords from your suggestion appear to be in the codebase.

Comment: I don't remember the details exactly in this answer but I've faced the same issue at it was resolved by using the default function (extracted from Gatsby's docs)